# Remove parenthesis with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to remove `(remove this)` from the `div` content. I'm using this, and it works, but it also changes the `bar` to `foo`?

```js
var replaced = $("div").html().replace(/\(.*\)/g, '');
$("div").html(replaced);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  foo (remove this)
</div>
<div>
  bar
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9uofygx0/1/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is because you're setting the HTML of *all* `div` elements. Instead you need to loop through them an update each one individually. To do that you can provide a function to `html()` which returns the new value, based on the original. Try this:

```js
$("div").html(function(i, html) {
  return html.replace(/\(.*\)/g, '');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>foo (remove this)</div>
<div>bar</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery doesn't know which div is which to replace the content. 
You can use each()

```
$( "div" ).each(function( index ) {
  $( this ).html($( this ).html().replace(/\(.*\)/g, ''))
});
```